# Code shrinking crashes the Mesibo functionalities

Tags: mesibo

We enabled minify and code shrinking in the build.gradle to make a release build. But doing so crashes the Mesibo native codes and the full app becomes unusable. Is there any way to solve this? It would be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look here, copy all the rules in your app,

https://github.com/mesibo/messenger-app-android/blob/master/app/proguard-rules.pro